# Python Reduce List of Dicts based on matching key/value pairs

Tags: python, merge, key-value

I have a list of dicts which specify flows (source to hop to destionation with their respective volume).
Now i want to split these flows into link (e.g. (source to hop with volume, hop to destination with volume) and merge all duplicate links together by summing up their volumes.

Since I'm new to python I'm wondering what a good approach would be. My first approach would be to loop through all flows and nest a loop through all links inside and check if the links already exists.

But if I have millions of flows, that might become quite ineffienct and slow I guess.

My starting data looks like this:

```
flows = [
    {
        'source': 1,
        'hop': 2,
        'destination': 3,
        'volume': 100,
    },{
        'source': 1,
        'hop': 2,
        'destination': 4,
        'volume': 50,
    },{
        'source': 2,
        'hop': 2,
        'destination': 4,
        'volume': 200,
    },
]
```

What my result should be:

```
links = [
    {
        'source': 1,
        'hop': 2,
        'volume': 150,
    },{
        'hop': 2,
        'destination': 3,
        'volume': 100,
    },{
        'hop': 2,
        'destination': 4,
        'volume': 250,
    },{
        'source': 2,
        'hop': 2,
        'volume': 200,
    },
]
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: [python pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) is your friend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can collect the links to two different dictionaries, one between source & hop and another one between hop & destination. Then you can easily create the result list separately from both of the dicts. Below [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is used which is `dict` like object with 0 as default value:

```
import pprint
from collections import Counter

flows = [
    {
        'source': 1,
        'hop': 2,
        'destination': 3,
        'volume': 100.5,
    },{
        'source': 1,
        'hop': 2,
        'destination': 4,
        'volume': 50,
    },{
        'source': 2,
        'hop': 2,
        'destination': 4,
        'volume': 200.7,
    },
]

sources = Counter()
hops = Counter()

for f in flows:
    sources[f['source'], f['hop']] += f['volume']
    hops[f['hop'], f['destination']] += f['volume']

res = [{'source': source, 'hop': hop, 'volume': vol} for (source, hop), vol in sources.items()]
res.extend([{'hop': hop, 'destination': dest, 'volume': vol} for (hop, dest), vol in hops.items()])
pprint.pprint(res)
```

Output:

```
[{'hop': 2, 'source': 1, 'volume': 150.5},
 {'hop': 2, 'source': 2, 'volume': 200.7},
 {'destination': 3, 'hop': 2, 'volume': 100.5},
 {'destination': 4, 'hop': 2, 'volume': 250.7}]
```

Above will run in **O(n)** time so it should work with millions of flows provided you have enough memory.

Comment: I like your approach, bu my volume is actually a float. So no easy counting I guess... 
Any ideas how to solve that?

Comment: @mxzwrnz Fixed the issue, for some reason I read the input like volume would have been a string which I then converted to int so that I could sum it. Remove the unnecessary code and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

pseudo algorithm:

1. create an empty result list/set/dictionary
2. loop over de flows list
3. split up each single flow into 2 links
4. for each of these 2 links test if they are already in the result list (based on the 2 nodes).
5. if not: add them. if yes: upgrade the volume of the one already in the list.

Comment: That's what I thought about too.
But my main question is, how step 4 can be done efficiently. How can I check that besides looping through my result list every time?

Comment: Use the `in` statement. Example: `(1, 2) in [(2, 3), (1, 2)]` will give `True`.

Comment: But I can't compare it like that because a tuple would contain source and tagert but also the volume which is likely to differ from link to link (and needs to be summed up).

Comment: Then you slice the tuple: `(1, 2, 98.7)[:2]` will give `(1, 2)`.

Comment: Is it possible to write `(1, 2, 50.5)[:2] in [(2, 3), (1, 2)][:2]` ? How can I compare a (partial) tuple with a list of tuple partials without looping over them?

Comment: @mxzwrnz Go to the Python command line and experiment with it.